# How can I correctly lazy load a json file in Vue.js to reduce bundle size?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, lazy-loading, lottie

I am using Vue.js and Laravel for my project and recently added two animations using a plugin named Lottie. Each animation is a component, and they both use an individual JSON file to animate a group of PNG images (similar to a PNG sequence). These two JSON files are stored locally in the project folder under the path **/public/data/**.

Firstly the JSON files are not being read unless I put in the absolute path (**/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json**), is there no way I can get this to work just by using **/data/filename.json**?

Secondly, when I add the code below in my component, my JS files are compiled to separate chunks as expected:

```
const animationData = () =>
  import("/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json");
```

I get the following error when the animation tries to run:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Function 

found in

---> <VueLottie>
```

However when I import my json file using a normal import in my component like below it works fine and shows the animation:

```
import animationData from "/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json";
```

My animation components are both set up like this:

```
<template>
        <vue-lottie ref="lottie" loop autoplay :data="animationData" :height="400" :width="400"></vue-lottie>
</template>

<script>
    import vueLottie from "vue-lottie-ssr";
    import animationData from '/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json'

    export default {
        name: 'animation',
        components: {
            vueLottie
        },
        data () {
            return {
                speed: 1,
                animationData
            }
        },
        computed: {
            lottie () {
                return this.$refs.lottie
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

I have also tried getting the JSON file via an axios call when the component mounts, but the same error occurs.

**Update**

I updated my code so that each component is lazy loaded instead of the JSON file. Like so:

```
components: {
  WinAnimation: () => import("./WinAnimation.vue");

  LoseAnimation: () => import("./LoseAnimation.vue");
}
```

However now I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown custom element: <win-animation> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

**Update 2**

I realised why I was getting an error message. The correct way was to add the following at the top of my script inside the parent vue file.

```
const winAnimation = () => import("./WinAnimation.vue");
const loseAnimation = () => import("./LoseAnimation.vue");
```

and then inside export default {...} I forgot to add the names, so:

```
components: { winAnimation, loseAnimation }
```

Now my code has been split and my app.js file size has reduced by almost a half! :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I tried axios also to get the json when the component mounts, but I received the same error message mentioned above. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Regarding your update: How exactly do you use your component in the template ?

Comment: It's ok, I figured out where I was going wrong, updated my question again - thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How do you resolve the dynamic import issue? i can not seems to dynamic import the lottie .json files. it does not display the animation without any error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st - don't use [vue-lottie](https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie) library. If you take a look at the source code, the main and only thing which should be provided by this library is component `src/lottie.vue` (+ it's dependency [lottie-web](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web)) but for some reason, NPM package also contains whole demo app **including** the demo JSON file (`src/assets/pinjump.json`)

If you take a look at `lottie.vue` component, its just very little and very simple wrapper for `lottie-web` which provides main functionality. By getting rid of `vue-lottie` you will get following benefits:

1. `vue-lottie` completely ignores one of the `lottie-web` options which is using [`path` instead of `animationData`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/wiki/loadAnimation-options#path-or-animationdatamandatory-at-least-one) - documentation is not very clear here but I would guess that by providing `path`, the library will try download the animation data ad-hoc so you don't need to include it in your bundle. Worth trying imho...
2. Loading animation data on demand

- why are you using dynamic import on JSON file instead of dynamically importing whole component ? By making separate chunk on component level, dynamic chunk will include not only your json data but also `lottie-web` which is also not small. And Vue will handle loading of the component without any additional code changes...
- if you still want to load on demand only your JSON data, you must understand that Webpack dynamic import (`import(".....")`) is returning Promise and `lottie-web` (and in turn `vue-lottie`) is expecting object. So you must do something like this:

```js
<script>
    import lottie from 'lottie-web';

    const animationData = () =>
       import("/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json");

    export default {
      mounted () {
        animationData().then(function(data) {
          this.anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
            // other options 
            animationData: data
          })
        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

### Update

You should be always very careful when considering adding 3rd party components into your project. One more thing I'v noticed is that `lottie-web` has [`destroy()`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#destroy) method in it's API. This indicates that it is creating some resources (DOM elements probably) which needs to be cleaned up. This is something `vue-lottie` component is not handling at all and can lead to nasty memory leaks in your app. You can read about the problem [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Thanks for the very informative response, I'll take a look at repurposing my project to use lottie-web instead of any wrapper packages. I have updated my question with your feedback, but I'm getting an error and not sure where I'm going wrong. This is my first time lazy loading a component :)

Answer (score 0):

When the `animationData` property is set it is a function, hence the line:

> Expected Object, got Function

It needs an object, not a function.
The function being:

```
const animationData = () =>
  import("/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json");
```

When defining the `animationData` property you need to set an object as its value. Then when mounting `fetch` the data (or use Axios if you prefer that) to update the `animationData` property on the component.

**N.B.** I have never used Vue, so I hope that what I am saying is correct.

```
export default {
    name: 'animation',
    components: {
        vueLottie
    },
    data () {
        return {
           speed: 1,
           animationData: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        lottie () {
            return this.$refs.lottie
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('/users/username/documents/projectname/public/data/filename.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.animationData = json;);
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as `vue-lottie` will call `lottie.loadAnimation` with empty object before the download is completed...